# Flutter, show ToolTips on first startup

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

iam trying to create like an decent onboarding, with tooltips, but my question right now is, is it possible to say only show this tooltip on the first startup. It should work like instagram. If you install instagram, it shows you also like tooltips, how to use it.

thanks for the help in advance. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) package. I'm not sure that it shows only once though.
If it doesn't, you can save persistent variables on the device with [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

Answer (score 0):

There's a new package that I find interesting for this use case: https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_tooltip, it comes with template use case so you can immediately plug it in your app. Kudos to the creator

Comment: show how to use it to solve the problem.